# The connection was interrupted while the page was loading - Firefox - Firebase - signInWithPopup()

Tags: javascript, facebook, firefox, firebase, firebase-authentication

I currently have a website that uses Firebase to authenticate users with facebook. I am using the Firebase JS SDK and signInWithPopup() method to authenticate my users.

The website works perfectly fine on Chrome, but when my users try to login with Firefox, they see the following error

```
The connection to wss://s-usc1c-nss-104.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5&s=Tqa1ImoPipzRYUPJ8vnALN7Fjzda2roZ&ns=my25pics was interrupted while the page was loading.
```

What are the possible reasons for this error and how or what would be the fastest way to fix it ?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using [signInWithRedirect](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#signInWithRedirect) instead of signInWithPopup for Firefox.  Note you'll also need to use [getRedirectResult](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#getRedirectResult) to get the authentication results after the user is redirected back to your page.

From the Firebase docs:

```
// Sign in with redirect:
auth.signInWithRedirect(provider)
// The user is redirected to the provider's sign in flow...
// Then redirected back to the app, where we check the redirect result:
auth.getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {
<save authentication results>
});
```